# Unity takes 500mb of memory on iOS, is this normal?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I am trying to track down some memory leak on ios, following the tutorial on https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000630203-How-to-find-memory-leaks-on-iOS

- Device: `iPad7,5`
- Unity: `2021.3.18f1`
- Xcode: `14.3.1`

[image: Memory Usage]

Once I load in the scene, the initial memory usage is already ~500mb. Then, the leak would add ~5-10mb in every click, whereas this scene would have 30 clicks, generating ~100-300mb of additional burden to the total memory. I have similar scenes that would contain only 10-20 clicks, which worked fine on installed devices, and the memory is somehow not overloaded.

I already tried with other instruments in xcode, including `discard events for freed memory` which showed only the leak of a few kb. And `Leak` didn't showed any leak during the clicks, but the memory size is keep increasing.

Therefore, I am first trying to reduce the initial memory usage and also solving the memory leak during the scene.